# Dúvida sobre Schema relacional do MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

```
const SurveySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    pages: [ //um survey pode ter várias páginas
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Page'
        }
    ]
});

const PageSchema = new Schema({
    name: String, 
    description: String,
    _type: String
});

const Page = mongoose.model('Page', PageSchema);
const Survey = mongoose.model('Survey', SurveySchema);
```

Digamos que já tenho dentro do meu banco (`Survey`) essa informação populada:

```
{
    _id: 'survey1',
    name: 'Algum nome',
    pages: ['58ff555', '123456789'] // Coleção de id's; cada id é uma página
}
```

Como eu faço uma referência com o id acima?

Se eu fizer da maneira abaixo, um `_id` aleatório será criado e não haverá ligação com o modelo de cima.

```
var pag = new Page({
    name: 'joeys',
    description: 'descricao 1'
});
pag.save(function(err, model) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json(model);
});
```

Uma outra dúvida:
Como gerar, de uma vez só, um único json com todas as informações desses dois esquemas ?

Comment: Deixa eu entender, você quer saber como sobrepor o `_id` por um valor já existente e você quer gerar um join entre os dois schemas?

Comment: @KhaosDoctor queria gerar um join entre os dois esquemas. Depois disso, eu gostaria de gerar um json com todas informações que foram adicionadas. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para setar o ID com um valor já existente você pode fazer de duas maneiras. A primeira é declarar explicitamente o `_id` no seu model:

```
const SurveySchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    pages: [ //um survey pode ter várias páginas
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Page'
        }
    ]
});
```

Ou então você pode desativar a auto geração do `_id`com `, { _id: false }`:

```
const SurveySchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    pages: [ //um survey pode ter várias páginas
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Page'
        }
    ]
}, {_id: false});
```

Quanto ao join, você já tem dentro de surveys uma lista de documentos que são suas páginas, ou seja, quando você utilizar o find ele já vai montar para você uma estrutura completa do JSON, pois você está referenciando outro schema dentro do primeiro. Mas talvez o método `populate` seja o que você procura, veja aqui:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001478/referencing-another-schema-in-mongoose